# Maximize does not work properly

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to use `Maximize` to find the maximum value of `f`, which is a polynomial in terms of `Sin[t]` and `Cos[t]`.

```
A = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}};
B = {{1, -2}, {-2, 0}};
p = {Cos[t], Sin[t]};
f = (p.A.A.p - (p.A.p)^2)(p.B.B.p - (p.B.p)^2)
Maximize[{f, 0 <= t <= \[Pi]/2}, t]
```

I thought it should be straightforward. However, the result I get is a very long expression, which does not make sense. I have no idea where I make a mistake.

[image: code image]

Comment: Try `Maximize[{Simplify@f, 0 <= t <= \[Pi]/2}, t] // N`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Version

"12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"

Clear["Global`*"]

A = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}};
B = {{1, -2}, {-2, 0}};
p = {Cos[t], Sin[t]};
```

`FullSimplify` prior to finding the maximum

```
f = (p.A.A.p - (p.A.p)^2) (p.B.B.p - (p.B.p)^2) // FullSimplify

(* 1/16 (9 + 7 Cos[4 t] + 6 Sin[4 t])^2 *)
```

`FullSimplify` after finding the maximum

```
{max, arg} = Maximize[{f, 0 <= t <= π/2}, t] // FullSimplify

(* {1/8 (83 + 9 Sqrt[85]), {t -> 1/2 ArcTan[1/6 (-7 + Sqrt[85])]}} *)
```

The approximate numeric values are

```
{max, arg} // N

(* {20.747, {t -> 0.177157}} *)
```

Visually,

```
Plot[f, {t, 0, π/2}, Epilog ->
  {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{t, f} /. arg]}]
```

[image]